# cbor encode and decode

Tags: cardano-cli, cbor

hope you all are doing great.
I am looking for a way to encode and decode the cborHex. I've done the following:

```
cardano-cli text-view decode-cbor --in-file wallet.vkey --out-file tx.alonzo
```

and I get the hex binary format but not a utf8 (human readable) format, how can this be done?

for reference, I've followed this question [How to decode cbor which is generated with cardano-cli build command?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/how-to-decode-cbor-which-is-generated-with-cardano-cli-build-command)

Answer (score 1):

I use python cbor2 library or https://cbor.me. In the case of a wallet vkey, it's just a hex value that it'll decode as. Something like a transaction will have more data types embedded in the CBOR.